# unable to delete a record in Data grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

error is coming while i'm tryin to delete a record from data source grid view.
error message is giving ."Must declare the scalar variable "@regid"." 
my delete query "DELETE from tablename where reg_id=@regid"

plz give me some solution

thanks
Churchill

Comment: How are you calling/using the query, need to see the code

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the paramater to Delete Command??

Add like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="reg_id" CellPadding="4"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Style="z-index: 100;
left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px">
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="@regid" Type="int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query is in stored procedure you must declare a variable to pass the value

i.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Delete
   @regid INT
AS

DELETE from tablename where reg_id=@regid
```

But if your query is hard-coded to the application you can concatinate the variable to the query like this

```
String sql = "DELETE from tablename where reg_id=" + regid.Text
```